# How to get column family and qualifier of a HBase Table

Tags: hbase, column-family, nosql

I want to use the following:

```
List<Cell> cells = sourcePut.get(CfBytes, QualBytes);
```

But it is returning me an empty list, since I am not specifying the correct column family and/or correct qualifier.

For my source table, how to view all column families and qualifiers?

I haven't created the HBase table, it was already available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution as follows:
1. To get the column family, scanning the table should work
2. To get the qualifier, following is the code I used:

```
Get g = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("xxxxxxx"));
//Within quotes above, the rowkey should be entered
            try {
                Result result = table.get(g);
                System.out.println(result.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes("")).firstEntry().getValue().toString());
                byte[] bytes = result.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes("<Column-Family Name>")).firstEntry().getKey();
                String s = new String(bytes);
                System.out.println("Qualifier Decrypted: " + s.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```